# Pinout diagram of Lora SX1272 RF board module

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, raspberry-pi

I already bought Lora SX1272 and Arduino . I would like to connect Arduino with Lora SX1272 RF board module.

However, I couldn't find the pinout diagram of Lora SX1272 RF board anywhere.

Could anyone tell me where can I get the pinout diagram?

I already emailed the vendor but haven't received the answer yet.

For the chip SX1272, the pin diagram is easy to find in Google.

However, what I want to know is the pin diagram of SX 1272 RF board module not the chip itself.

Below are the images of the chip and SX1272 RF board module:

[image]

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: You didn't try Googling it, did you? Because I'm pretty sure the second result is the datasheet.

Comment: Failing Google, visit Semtech's web page...

Comment: Well, I tried but not sure if the second result is right. I am not familiar with this. http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/sx1272.pdf

Comment: I have just edited the post. What I want to know is the pin diagram of SX1272 RF board module not the chip (SX1272) pin diagram.

Comment: Google will tell you that the pinout is similar to XBee, and will also turn up forum posts describing the pinout.

Comment: Please post a link. I did say that I am not familiar with this and I did google a lot. It may be easy to you but not to me. I know how to google, don't tell me that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Libelium's employee stated in this [topic](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=7880):

> Function -> Pin number
>
> MOSI -> 11
>
> MISO -> 4
>
> SCLK -> 18
>
> SSEL -> 17

[image]

Additional information:

> You can find DIO0 at **pin 12 on the module** but DIO1 is not routed.